# Clear cache in WebView2 in C# (Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, caching, webview2

My name is Zaid. I am a beginner-intermediate in c#.

I have an application which has a WebView2 control called *webView21*.  I am opening a website and doing my business (just typing and searching).

What I want done, is that when the user closes the form *(and triggers the FormClosed event)*, I want to clear all cache saved from the websites which he visited.

How is this to be done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/clear-browsing-data?tabs=csharp

Comment: Does clearing browsing data clear cache also, @dr.null??

Comment: Also, how to put it in the code? I tried this: `webView21.ClearBrowsingDataAsync();` and above, I put the code `System.Threading.Tasks.Task ClearBrowsingDataAsync();`. Please help me out ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The parameterless method wipes out the profile-data. Everything defined in [CoreWebView2BrowsingDataKinds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2browsingdatakinds?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1774.30). If you need to clear a specific type of data, then use the method overload that takes datakind(s) bitwise value.

Comment: Call it from async method/task/event. i.e: `private async void YourForm_FormClosed(...) { await webView21.ClearBrowsingDataAsync(); }`.